# display images dynamically from folder using php

Tags: php

i am new to php i am working on image upload to folder and displaying it from the same folder and added checkbox to each diasplayed image.. but my problem is images are displaying one below the other but i want to diasply each image and the corresponding checkbox in sperate column can any one pls help me out in this thanks in advance..
 here is my code.

```
<?php

$path = "small";
$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open folder");

while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle))) {

if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != 'Thumbs.db')
{

echo "<input type=CHECKBOX name=$file>";
echo "<img src='small/$file' alt='$file'><br />";
}
}
closedir($dir_handle);

?>
```

Comment: Please edit your post and make your PHP code was displayed as a code.

Comment: If you want them in columns, you can always use a table. Or have fun aligning them with CSS. This code is a mess though.

Comment: By the way Patel this question should be tagged in PHP

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to do the following

```
<?php

$path = "uploads";
$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open folder");
echo "<table>";
echo"<tr>";
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle))) {

if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != 'Thumbs.db'){
echo "<td><input type=CHECKBOX name=$file></td>";
echo "<td><img src='uploads/$file' alt='$file'><br>
      $file
  </td>";
}
}
echo"<tr/>";
echo"</table>";
closedir($dir_handle);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use table here

```
<?php

$path = "small";
$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open folder");
echo "<table>";
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle))) {

if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != 'Thumbs.db')
{
echo"<tr>";
echo "<td><input type=CHECKBOX name=$file></td>";
echo "<td><img src='small/$file' alt='$file'></td>";
echo"<tr/>";
}
}
echo"</table>";
closedir($dir_handle);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you could display a table or definitions list.

```
<table>
    ...
    <tbody>
         <tr>
              <td>checkbox here</td>
              <td>image here</td>
         </tr>
         ...
    ...
</table>

<!-- or -->

<dl>
    <dt>image here</dt>
    <dd>checkbox here</dt>
</dl>
```

So simply display the beginning of the table/list (`<table><thead>....<tbody>`/`<dl>`) then display in loop your images with checkboxes

```
while (...) {
    ...
    echo '<dt>image</dt><dd>checbox</dd>'); //or a table row
}
```

Finally display the ending of table/list (`</tbody></table>`/`</dl>`).